# Sending GSP table data to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, grails, export

I've just started learning Grails and it looks awesome. I'm currently playing with Export plugin. I have a table in GSP and a submit button. Clicking the button should export table data (instances of domain class) to a .csv file. Can anyone help me with this? I'm guessing  I could have hidden field in table which would hold domain model instance id, than get all those id's with jQuery and send it with Ajax as JSON to controller's action and than pass that to exportService. Should I use $.ajax method or something else? Or there is way to do this without ajax?

I'm new to both Grails and jQuery/Ajax so some simple example would be great. Thanks.

EDIT:

```
def results = bookCriteria.list(max: params.max as Integer, offset: params.offset as Integer) {
        and {
                'eq'("category","history")
                 ne("status", "Rented")

            }

    }
if(params?.format && params.format != "html"){
        response.contentType = ConfigurationHolder.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.${params.extension}")

      exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream, results, [:], [:])

    }
```

I have something like this in controller. But it returns only first 50 rows (because of the paging). How to manage to have paging but to be able to export all coresponding rows?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to send the data from your table to the server if the user could modify the values of your table. Is this really your usecase? If not - you don't need to use AJAX.

Look at the [description of the plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/export). There you could find some basic examples.

In general you do a simple request to your action, fetch the data you want to export, call the `exportService` and modify the `response` as described on the plugin page.

Basic example from the plugin page:

```
def list = {
   if(!params.max) params.max = 10

   if(params?.format && params.format != "html"){
      response.contentType = ConfigurationHolder.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]    
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=books.${params.extension}")

      exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream,Book.list(params), [:], [:]) 
   }
   [ bookInstanceList: Book.list( params ) ] 
}
```

**Edit:**
Here is some code how you could get all books in case of export:

```
def results = bookCriteria.list {
   and {
      'eq'("category","history")
      ne("status", "Rented")
   }

   if(!params?.format || params.format == "html") {
      maxResults(params.max.toInteger())
      firstResult(params.offset.toInteger())
   }
}
```

You could replace `if(!params?.format || params.format == "html")` by any other condition that indicates that you don't want to list all results. Hope that helps ...

Comment: Yes, but what if I don't want to export all domain class instances? For example what if I did some kind of filtering so in GSP table there are only some of my domain class instances? Am I missing something?

Comment: This is just an example. You could replace `Book.list(params)` by any other list of instances. To create the list of instances to export, you could use all kind of groovy/grails methods ([criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html), [query](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html), [finder](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html), etc.) to select your disired instances. How do you filtered the instances of your GSP table?

Comment: I used something like def bookList = Book.executeQuery("select ...") in action and I pass it to GSP like this [bookInstanceList:bookList, bookInstanceTotal:bookList.count()]

Comment: Then you could also use the result of this query as parameter for `exportService.export()` ... If you still need help - please provide some code.

Comment: Thank you! I'll tinker with it and if I dont make it work I'll post some code.